# Can I say "bottlenecks"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

For example, I want to tell the limitation of the system.

Is the plural form *bottlenecks* correct?

> Here are the bottle necks in our system to achieve this requirement.
>
> 1. <<<
> 2. <<<

Is the following sentence correct?

> Here are the bottle necks in our system to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you introduced new bottlenecks in order to meet some requirement, or that there are bottlenecks which prevent you from meeting some requirement?

Comment: here are bottlenecks which prevent you from meeting some requirement?  This is what I want to say.

Comment: Bottleneck can also be a verb. "I found that it was my GPU that was **bottlenecking** my computer."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: yes, you can use a plural form.

However, keep in mind the meaning of bottleneck: it's an issue limiting progress, while *nothing else* stands in the way of progress occurring. Imagine trying to build a house using a teaspoon to scoop up the cement: that would be a bottleneck! On the other hand, if you're out of bricks, cement and wood, then you just have problems, or in 'manager language', you have **challenges** to overcome.

The sentence does sound slightly odd to me: it sounds a bit like you **need** the bottlenecks to achieve your goals! More correct would be *'Here are the bottlenecks in our system to achieving this requirement'* (using 'a bottleneck to' as a [noun+preposition combination](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-can-a-gerund-be-used-after-to/)) or *'Here are bottlenecks in our system that prevent us from meeting this requirement'*.

From what I see in online dictionaries, it is spelled **bottlenecks** or **bottle-necks**, not *bottle necks*.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

[OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bottleneck?q=bottleneck) has an entry with its plural form

> *to create/eliminate **bottlenecks** in the manufacturing process*

Just take care that you don't write both words separately -bottle and neck!